# Sort vector in java

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

I have a Vector in my class, which I declared as `Vector v = new Vector();`. When I print the vector in console I get the values as `[120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 210, 80]` . Now I need to sort this vector in ascending order.

How can I do that? Can anybody help me in doing this..

Thanks in advance.
Sundeep.S

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(v)`. Also don't use raw types.  `Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections#sort()` to sort a vector. It will sort in ascending order. Look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method:

```
Collections.sort(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort(v)` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

use: `java.util.Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

This would fulfill your requirements:

```
List v = new Vector(); //rather use List instead of Vector (more elegant style)
//adding of values here
Colletions.sort(v);
System.out.println(v.toString());
```